# How to force a html5 video to load fully?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I have a few html5 videos on a page. When I first enter the page, they load correctly - I can see the correct frame size, play the video etc. etc. After going to another page and coming back to the video page the frames are not high enough and the video doesn't play, doesn't go fullscreen etc.

In my opinion it's something with video loading. I tried using onloadeddata without success (I might have used it wrong though, newbie here).

Is there any way the video can be forced to load? Like a loop checking if the videos are loaded, if not - loading them?

UPDATE: Here's the code.

```
var content = '';
    var index;
    $.post('api/getVideo.php', {id: id}, function(data) {
    //console.log(data);

        for (index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            content = content + '<div class="col-md-6 video-col"> <button id="play" class="full-play-button"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>' +
                    '<video id="video1" class="video-small"> <source src="'+data[index]["Path"] + '"type="video/'+data[index]["Typ"]+'" class="video-file"> </video><h3 class="video-title">'+
                    data[index]["Tytul"]+'</h3></div>';
        }
    }, "json");
```

Comment: Post updated. Like I said, I tried onloaddata and also tried playing around with checking if readyState === 4 (but again, newbie).

Comment: How did you use `onloadeddata` ?? That's not jQuery function?

Comment: I don't remember exactly now, I tried that yesterday, but it was about going full screen - making video1.play() only onloadeddata to prevent from full screen fireing without video loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a typo in your source tag. Try changing '"type="video/' to '"type=video/"'. Modern browsers don't require the type attribute, anymore, so try removing '"type="video/'+data[index]["Typ"]+' completely. I don't have enough info to test your code, but it looks like a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

From [MediaAPI](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#media-elements) docs,

The Media API also contains a `load()` method which: "Causes the element to reset and start selecting and loading a new media resource from scratch." (
Load element causes browser to run [media element load algorithm](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#media-element-load-algorithm))

You can trigger load while returning back from the new page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I determine "returning back from the new page"? With my very small javascript knowledge I assume I should be able to add an event listener, something like: when "comingBackToPage" load() ?

Comment: It's hard for me to say if this would work or not. I asked a more advanced collegue who managed to find a solution - I don't really understand how so unfortunately I can't describe it here. +1 though for making me aware that load() might mean two different things.

Comment: But the answer is not correct. The load method actually does the same thing, that is done, if you construct a video and insert it into the dom. Calling load right after this doesn't load the video, it resets and re-parses the video element. this is usefull, if you change the child source elements.

Answer (score 0):

In short this is not fully possible. For short videos you can set the [preload attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload) to "auto" or the empty string "". This means, that you want the browser to preload the source entirly.

Unfortunatley, in case of long videos, the video isn't fully downloaded by most browsers. In case of mobile browser explicitly iOS. The preload attribute doesn't work. So the way to this look like this:

```
<video preload="" controls="">
    <source src="my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="my-video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```